# EntityFramework 6 Connection Closed

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-connection

I did upgrade to the EF 6 and when I do this query is showing this error:

> ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Code:

```
var db = new Entity2Entities();
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

var ids = db.PersonBase.SqlQuery(Utils.Query(param, "PersonBase"))
                       .Select(x => x.Id);
var result = db.Employee.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));
```

Comment: db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

var ids = db.PersonBase.SqlQuery(Utils.Query(param,"PersonBase")).Select(x => x.Id);

db.Database.Connection.Open();

var result = db.Employee.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF 6 is in alpha state, things can change in the future. I didnt try this but maybe you have to do

```
db.Database.Connection.Open();
```

before executing SqlQuery method.

Comment: db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
                

                var ids = db.PersonBase.SqlQuery(Utils.Query(param, "PersonBase")).Select(x => x.Id);
                db.Database.Connection.Open();
                var result = db.Employee.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));